# Set max size as native image size on responsive image jquery resizer

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

Forewarning: I am a major newbie.

I have this bit of code I am using that resizes images on my site based on how large the browser window is. The problem is, the images are also being enlarged pass their native size, creating ugly & pixely images. I was wondering if:

There is a way to add a bit of code that will prevent the image from enlarging past its original uploaded size.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I currently have:

```
(function( $ ) {

$.fn.aeImageResize = function( params ) {

var aspectRatio = 0
// Nasty I know but it's done only once, so not too bad I guess
// Alternate suggestions welcome :)
,   isIE6 = $.browser.msie && (6 == ~~ $.browser.version)
;

// We cannot do much unless we have one of these
if ( !params.height && !params.width ) {
return this;
}

// Calculate aspect ratio now, if possible
if ( params.height && params.width ) {
aspectRatio = params.width / params.height;
}

// Attach handler to load
// Handler is executed just once per element
// Load event required for Webkit browsers
return this.one( "load", function() {

// Remove all attributes and CSS rules
this.removeAttribute( "height" );

this.style.height = "";

var imgHeight = this.height
, imgWidth = this.width
, imgAspectRatio = imgWidth / imgHeight
, bxHeight = params.height
, bxWidth = params.width
, bxAspectRatio = aspectRatio;

// Work the magic!
// If one parameter is missing, we just force calculate it
if ( !bxAspectRatio ) {
if ( bxHeight ) {
bxAspectRatio = imgAspectRatio + 1;
} else {
bxAspectRatio = imgAspectRatio - 1;
}
}

// Only resize the images that need resizing


if ( imgAspectRatio > bxAspectRatio ) {
bxHeight = ~~ ( imgHeight / imgWidth * bxWidth );
} else {
bxWidth = ~~ ( imgWidth / imgHeight * bxHeight );
}

this.height = bxHeight-100;

})
.each(function() {

// Trigger load event (for Gecko and MSIE)
if ( this.complete || isIE6 ) {
$( this ).trigger( "load" );
}
});
};
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the beginning of the function:

```
if (params.height < this.height ||
    params.width < this.width)
{
  return this;
}
```